# Rearming a promise when used with setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to trigger a new random number every 30 seconds of every minute. I have kind of working. It fires once. How do I rearm my promise after it fires, so it can fire again in 30 seconds?

```js
    let token = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let id = setInterval(function() {
        let sec = new Date().getSeconds()
        if ( sec === 0 || sec === 30 ) {
            setInterval(getToken, 30000);
            getToken();        
            clearInterval(id);
        }
      },1000);

      function getToken(){
        token = Math.random()
        resolve(token)
      }
    })

    console.log(await token)
```

Comment: Why do you need this to be a `Promise`?

Comment: I'm trying to return `token` as a callback in a higher scoped function.

Comment: Once a promise has been settled (resolved or rejected) it's done, you can't rearm/reset it. Why not make `token` a function that returns a promise? Or use a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? Do you want to generate a new token every 30 seconds then save it somewhere?

Comment: @goto1 yes, essentially.. I need the token variable available as it changes. MDN has an example of using promises with setInterval, but it's kind of confusing and not directly applicable because I'm using both setInterval and setTimeout

Comment: Why not just use `setInterval` that updates a `token` variable every 30 seconds? I don't see why you'd want a `Promise` here

Comment: I'm running into scope issues if I don't `Promise`. I need `token` available outside of setInterval. The code as written works correctly, but only once. I need it to work every 30 seconds

Comment: @robertklep A generator sounds interesting.. I will look into this. Thank you!

Comment: Do you expect the single statement `console.log(await token)` to log multiple tokens? That's not how promises work, you can only resolve them once.

Comment: @robertklep I find myself stuck in scope hell with a generator also.

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue. I will create a new question once I have time to build it out exactly into a minimal reproducible example. However, I think what I need is clearly described in this question.